# File descriptor leaks on Linux

Tags: java, linux, file-descriptor, resource-leak

I have an application which leaks thousands of file descriptors. `lsof` shows many opened regular files, but in memory dump of the application I have not found many opened fd - there are only 100-200 `java.io.FileDescriptor` instances, many of them are garbage (unreachable). As far as I can see the memory dump should show all of file descriptors from the `lsof` output. How to find the remaining file descriptors?

Comment: Another approach would be to *avoid* "unfinished resources" in the first place: Do or didn't you use "try-with-resources" in the source code you control yourself?

Comment: Yes, we use "try-with-resource". It's a bug in code. I have analyzed huge rows of code, but no success... Project is very big. The idea was to check reachibility scope in memory dump for descriptor leaks.

Comment: Please edit information facilitating useful answers into the post. Did you try to make head or tail of the "names" of the files lsof reports open (-Fn)? Result?

Comment: We have filtered lsof output by process id with grep.

Comment: How do you know there are file descriptor leaks?

Comment: lsof shows many files like /path_to_file/myfile.bin (deleted), and there are open fd in /proc/<pid>/fd. The files already deleted, but descriptors not closed.

Comment: You need to add more detail to this question to get more help. I suggest you track down all known files in file descriptor list which appear suspicious - for example is there an app in your codebase which writes names like "myfile.bin" and isn't following code standards (try/resources handling)?

Comment: If there are some code not using try/resource handling then there will be many FileDescriptor class instances, do not it? But in memory dump i see only 200-300 FileDescriptor instances. I think there is some bug in JDK or OS. I will trace the JVM and OS calls to find the leaks.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue. In the code there where RandomAccessFile used. This class has no finalyzer in contrast to FileOutpuStream or FileInputStream. So, in one place the stream usage has complex logic and where not closed properly. Garbage collector cleans RandomAccessFile instances and it's FileDescriptor - this lead us to fd leaks.